# Setting up AndroidViewClient on Windows 8 - Version Confusion

Tags: androidviewclient

I used easy_install to install androidviewclient [v.5.4.3](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/androidviewclient/5.4.3). I also downloaded androidviewclient-master from [here](https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient). (which is v.5.1.1 for some reason)

My question is, what should I set ANDROID_VIEW_CLIENT_HOME? The path to where I have androidviewclient-master? or to where the .egg was installed?

The reason I ask is because the .egg does not have examples or a bunch of other files.

I am a little confused on where the best place to get this tool from and which to use (or both).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should set `ANDROID_VIEW_CLIENT_HOME` parameter as a path to `androidviewclient-master`.

For example if you extracted `androidviewclient-master` files directly on `C:\` then set `ANDROID_VIEW_CLIENT_HOME = C:\AndroidViewClient-master\AndroidViewClient`

If you want to download the latest `AndroidViewClient` version just sign up and login to the page you mentioned above https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient. Then you will find "Download ZIP" on the right side of the page there.

You may also download it from https://pypi.python.org/pypi/androidviewclient/ 7.0.2 version is already available there.

Comment: Ok. I downloaded the zip and am using it. The download from [pypi](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/androidviewclient/) does not seem to have things like the example files. 
Is there a way to check which version my AndroidViewClient is?

Comment: In `C:\AndroidViewClient-master\AndroidViewClient` you have setup.py it contains the version number